# Coverity use for simple HalloWorld

Tags: c, makefile, code-analysis, coverity

I'd like to use Coverity on my local virtual machine. I created simple HalloWorld and used Coverity Wizard to set up analysis. Everything works fine. The problem is when I want to run Coverity from terminal. It doesn't "find" my makefile.

I have a directory halloworld with one .c file and makefile. I'm able to successfully build program with make cmd. For Coverity I run commands in this order:

1. ./cov-configure --gcc
2. ./cov-build --dir "usr/halloworld/" make

RESPONSE:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

makefile:

```
all: test.exe

test.exe: test.o
     gcc -o test.exe test.o

test.o: test.c
     gcc -c test.c

clean:
     rm -rf test.o test.c
```

I am pretty sure it's just a typo or missing argument or something similar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I mixed up directories. cov-build should be run in directory with source files and directory after --dir is just a place for intermediate directory which will be created. Thanks everyone.